# Deployment model name missing in from Azure Open AI Activity Logs

Tags: azure-openai

I have created a test deployment and would like to get an entry in the Azure Activity Logs . I can see the entry under "MICROSOFT.COGNITIVESERVICES/ACCOUNTS/DEPLOYMENTS/WRITE" category when i write KQL query, but not model name using which deployment is created. is it by schema definition that model name is not captured?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you will have deployment name but don't have "original model name" in the ActivityLog.

You can still get the information by calling the `Resources` REST API:

Sample request:

```
GET https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/SUB_ID/resourcegroups/RG_NAME/providers/Microsoft.CognitiveServices/accounts/OPEN_AI_RESOURCE_NAME/deployments/DEPLOYMENT_NAME?api-version=2023-05-01
```

Response:

```
{
  "id": "/SUB_ID/resourcegroups/RG_NAME/providers/Microsoft.CognitiveServices/accounts/OPEN_AI_RESOURCE_NAME/deployments/DEPLOYMENT_NAME",
  "type": "Microsoft.CognitiveServices/accounts/deployments",
  "name": "DEPLOYMENT_NAME",
  "sku": {
    "name": "Standard",
    "capacity": 120
  },
  "properties": {
    "model": {
      "format": "OpenAI",
      "name": "gpt-35-turbo",
      "version": "0613"
    },
    "versionUpgradeOption": "OnceCurrentVersionExpired",
    "capabilities": {
      "chatCompletion": "true"
    },
    "raiPolicyName": "Microsoft.Default",
    "provisioningState": "Succeeded",
    "rateLimits": [
      {
        "key": "request",
        "renewalPeriod": 10,
        "count": 120
      },
      {
        "key": "token",
        "renewalPeriod": 60,
        "count": 120000
      }
    ]
  },
  "systemData": {
    "createdBy": "xxxxxxx@xxxxxx.com",
    "createdByType": "User",
    "createdAt": "2023-10-23T15:04:17.8235277Z",
    "lastModifiedBy": "xxxxxxx@xxxxxx.com",
    "lastModifiedByType": "User",
    "lastModifiedAt": "2023-10-23T15:04:17.8235277Z"
  },
  "etag": "\"...\""
}
```

=> You got model and version in the properties/model block